# Really long URL causes open_basedir restriction error in CakePHP view cache checking

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I'm having a problem where PHP is reporting an open_basedir restriction error when CakePHP is trying to check if the cache for a view exists.

The problem is that the URL has a very long GET query after it, as in http://example.com/index/?sodmfsodifnsodfnsodfnsoidnfsodinfsiodnfsodinfsiodfn and so on.

CakePHP is converting this into a file name for the cache, and then PHP is throwing a warning when file_exists is called. To check if the view cache exists.

This is a problem, cause on my development machine PHP errors are on and I can't perform a redirect. Since this warning is thrown during dispatch.

Has anyone experienced this problem, and recommended solutions? If there is a file name length restriction for file_exists, then maybe this should be a bug reported to the CakePHP developers.

Comment: The maximum file name limit for most of the existent operating systems is 255 bytes, so, if you are over that, you are in trouble!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only correct answer was to disable caching in CakePHP, and/or upgrade to CakePHP 2.0 so that a different cache engine could be used or developed.